# Update from PHP 7.1 to 7.3 and error one.com

Tags: php

my website domain from one.com updated php from 7.1 to 7.3 since then I am receiving error can some help me howto update the scripts manually, I have identified where changes are required but don't know what to change.

> PHP Warning: set_time_limit(): Cannot set max execution time limit due to system policy in /customers/3/9/4/lushcompany.co.uk/httpd.www/admin/controller/openbay/openbay.php on line 1054

I am in `admin/controller/openbay/openbay.php` on line 1054 but don't know what to change and these error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in /customers/3/9/4/lushcompany.co.uk/httpd.www/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_amazon.php:337 Stack trace: #0 /customers/3/9/4/lushcompany.co.uk/httpd.www/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_amazon.php(296): Amazon->encrypt('{"Apple/Cinnam...', '?$\xEBu=H&\n\xF2\xF5K\xCBMr*...', true) #1 /customers/3/9/4/lushcompany.co.uk/httpd.www/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_amazon.php(239): Amazon->callWithResponse('product/UpdateQ...', Array) #2 /customers/3/9/4/lushcompany.co.uk/httpd.www/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_amazon.php(86): Amazon->updateQuantities(Array) #3 /customers/3/9/4/lushcompany.co.uk/httpd.www/system/library/openbay.php(63): Amazon->productUpdateListen('3216', Array) #4 /customers/3/9/4/lushcompany.co.uk/httpd.www/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_controller_catalog_product.php(76): Openbay->productUpdateListen('3216', Array) #5 /customers/3/9/4/lushcompany.co.uk/httpd.www/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_front.php(42): ControllerCatalogProdu in /customers/3/9/4/lushcompany.co.uk/httpd.www/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_amazon.php on line 337

I have identified the location

> 2019-11-06 11:18:36 - PHP Warning:  set_time_limit(): Cannot set max execution time limit due to system policy in /customers/3/9/4/lushcompany.co.uk/httpd.www/admin/controller/openbay/openbay.php on line 1054

What do I need to change?

Comment: `set_time_limit()` has been disabled in the central php config file used by your host. As for `mcrypt_module_open()` it has been [deprecated by php 7.1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-module-open.php) and your code should be rewritten to not rely on it. It's impossible to say more without knowing how both functions are used in your code.

Comment: many thanks any idea what to  rewrite i have found the file but do know what rewrite and which line to search